# how reference type assignment performs in java

Tags: java, variable-assignment

As I know, when one object is assigned to another object (e.g. o2 = o1), o2 points to the actual object that o1 points. Therefore, any change in the actual object is visible for both objects.
suppose we have two classes named A1 and A2 as follows:

```
class A1{
    int a;  A2 a2;
    A1(int a, A2 a2) { 
        this.a = a; this.a2 = a2; }
    public void setA(int a) { this.a = a;}
    public void setA2(A2 a2) { this.a2 = a2;}
    public int getA() { return a;}
    public A2 getA2() { return a2;}
}

class A2 {
    int b;
    A2(int b) { this.b = b;}
    public void setB(int b) { this.b = b;}
    public int getB() { return b;}
}
```

in the main function we have:

```
A1 o1 = new A1(10, new A2(20));
A1 o2 = o1;
System.out.println("o2==="+o2.toString());
o1.setA(12);
o1.setA2(new A2(22));
System.out.println("o2==="+o2.toString());
```

The result is as follow:

```
o2=(10,20)
o2=(12,22)
```

By A1 o2 = o1 statement, the o2.a2 points to the o1.a2 (they are refrenced type). So, by executing o1.setA2(new A2(22)) statement, a new object for o1.a2 is created but the previous object, which o2.a2 is pointing to, should not changed. Therefore I expect the second output must be (12,20).
Please help me why the second output is (12,22) not (12,20)???

Answer (score 0):

o2 is pointing to the original A1 object so changes made to this A1 object will be seen by o1 and o2.

```
A1 o1 = new A1(10, new A2(20)); //o1 points to a new A1 object
A1 o2 = o1; //o2 now points to the A1 object o1 points to
System.out.println("o2==="+o2.toString());
o1.setA(12); //setting the original A1 objects a to 12;
o1.setA2(new A2(22)); // setting the original A1 object's A2's b to 22.
System.out.println("o2==="+o2.toString());  // o2 still refers to the original A1 object so it will reflect the changes
```

Comment: suppose m1 be the location of o1.a2. when the A1 o2 = o1 executes, both of o1.a2 and o2.a2 are pointing to m1. when o1.setA2(new A2(22)) is invoked, first new A2 object is created (let m2 be the location of the new object) then o1.a2 point to m2. but o2.a2 must points to m1. if we use o1.getA2().setB(22), it is true that second output be (12,22) but in this situation it is not clear why thia happens???

Answer (score 0):

> As I know, when one object is assigned to another object (e.g. o2 =
>   o1), o2 points to the actual object that o1 points. **Therefore, any
>   change in the actual object is visible for both objects**.

```
A1 o2 = o1;
```

Here is the part you assign one object to another.

```
o1.setA(12);
o1.setA2(new A2(22));
```

You mutate o1 , **Therefore, any change in the actual object is visible for both objects**

```
System.out.println("o2==="+o2.toString());
```

Here we see that changes in o1 are reflected in o2.

**UPDATE**

> suppose m1 be the location of o1.a2. when the A1 o2 = o1 executes,
>   both of o1.a2 and o2.a2 are pointing to m1. when o1.setA2(new A2(22))
>   is invoked, first new A2 object is created (let m2 be the location of
>   the new object) then o1.a2 point to m2. but o2.a2 must points to m1.
>   if we use o1.getA2().setB(22), it is true that second output be
>   (12,22) but in this situation it is not clear why thia happens???

What happen is that you think that java passed by reference but not. **Java pass by value the reference**.

Simple example :

```
public static void method1(A a){
  a.setB("B");  
}

public static void method2(A a){
  a= new A();
  a.setB("B");
}

public static void main(String args []){
    A a = new A();
    a.setB("A");
    method2(a);
    System.out.println(a.getB()); // will print "A"
    method1(a.getB()); // will print "B"

}
```

Comment: suppose m1 be the location of o1.a2. when the A1 o2 = o1 executes, both of o1.a2 and o2.a2 are pointing to m1. when o1.setA2(new A2(22)) is invoked, first new A2 object is created (let m2 be the location of the new object) then o1.a2 point to m2. but o2.a2 must points to m1. if we use o1.getA2().setB(22), it is true that second output be (12,22) but in this situation it is not clear why thia happens???

Comment: @user90723014 i update the answer , hope it helps to understand

Answer (score 0):

Since o1 and o2 pointing to the same object, changes on o1 will be seen by both of o1 and o2.
You said "setA2(new A2(22)) statement, a new object for o1.a2 is created but the previous object, which o2.a2 is pointing to, should not changed."
This may be wrong. In this case, o1.a2 is created, that means o1.a2 points to a new object, **but notice, o2.a2 hold the same reference as o1.a2 does.** So, the output can be expected as o2=(12,22).

Comment: suppose m1 be the location of o1.a2. when the A1 o2 = o1 executes, both of o1.a2 and o2.a2 are pointing to m1. when o1.setA2(new A2(22)) is invoked, first new A2 object is created (let m2 be the location of the new object) then o1.a2 point to m2. but o2.a2 must points to m1. if we use o1.getA2().setB(22), it is true that second output be (12,22) but in this situation it is not clear why thia happens???

Comment: @user90723014 As what I said just now, NOTICE! o1 and o2 point to the same object, that means, o1.a2 and o2.a2 is also the same object. When o1.a2 points to m2, o2.a2 points to m2 as well.

Comment: according to your answer the following main function must output (90,90) because o2 points to o1 but it produces (10, 20). I can't differentiate between this two situations:
 A1 o1 = new A1(10, new A2(20));
 A1 o2 = o1;
 o1 = new A1(90, new A2(90));
 System.out.println("o2==="+o2.toString());

Comment: @user90723014 It's very clear that you've not understood what "any change on the actual object is visible for both objects" exactly means. Let's suppose two virables o1,o2 pointing to the same object m, in the first case, you change the value of m **(ACTUAL OBJECT)** by o1 or o2, then this change will be seen by both of them. Another case is you're attempting to change o1's reference **(NOT ACTUAL OBJECT)**. Under this situation, o2 still points to m, but o1 not. This causes o1 and o2 in no relations.